# Error with file permissions when creating Outlook PST archive

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to set up AutoArchive in Outlook, but no matter where I try to create the PST file, Outlook gives me an error `The file name is not valid`.

I've tried clicking on the Browse button and creating a file `C:\Users\username\Documents\Outlook Files\archive.pst`, but when I click OK, Outlook tells me `You don't have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission.`

The problem is that I'm the owner of that folder and my account is an administrator.

I've tried to create the file on different drives and in other directories where I know I have write permissions, like `C:\archive.pst` and `D:\archive.pst`, but all of them results in the same error. I've also tried running Outlook as an administrator to no avail.

The version of Outlook I'm using is from Office Professional Plus 2013.

Comment: This sounds like a domain policy and/or Exchange policy.  Have you asked for assistance from your IT department?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, it sounds like a plausible explanation. I will contact our IT help desk.

Answer (score 1):

This is the result of applying the *"Prevent users from adding PSTs to Outlook profiles and/or prevent using Sharing-Exclusive PSTs"* group policy. You need to contact your sysadmin as stated in the error message.

You may also need to configure *"Auto Archive Settings"* group policy.